# Unable to Load LWR Assets on Windows Machine

Tags: lightning-web-components, node.js, lightning-web-runtime

I installed the latest version of LWR (0.10.3) for Node.js on my Windows machine, following the directions found at https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/platform/lwr/guide/lwr-get-started.html. I created the project as a markdown static site.

The server starts but it's unable to locate the CSS file. Here's the error I get:

```
[
  {
    description: {
      category: 'lwrUnresolvable/asset',
      advice: [],
      message: '404: Could not find asset at "/\\public\\assets\\css\\main.css"'
    }
  }
]
```

I'd appreciate any and all advice.

Comment: you need to use [WSL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/about) for it to work on windoes

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved that by modifying the path - for example:
./assets/styles/salesforce-lightning-design-system.css
But still there much more issues, for example it is not possible to run simple appliacation in production mode on windows because of different error:
[image]